# C# entity framework connection to Azure MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, entity-framework

I have a problem updating database in Azure MySql database, I can connect to my db thru SSMS with no problems but when i try do dontet ef database update i get error

```
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.15 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using prov
ider 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore:6.0.10+MySQL8.0.32' with options: None
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of
the specified MySQL hosts.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10051): PrÃ³ba przeprowadzenia operacj
i, wykonywanej przez gniazdo, na nieosiÄ…galnej sieci.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(Soc
ketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.T
asks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(
Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.CompleteConnectAsync(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.<>c.<Open>b__40_0(Exception ex)
   at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings
)
   at MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySqlConnection conn
ection, String originalConnectionString, String& connectionString, Boolean mySql
PoolManager)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.<>c__Displ
ayClass16_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClas
s12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[
TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,T
Result](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 veri
fySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,T
Result](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boo
lean retryOnNotExists)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateD
atabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(
String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c_
_DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execu
te(Action action)
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

this is my connection string

```
"con": "Data Source=tcp:amcia.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=amcia;User ID=gryTerAdmin@amcia;Password=<password>;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

and i use this to connect to db in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    IConfiguration configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("con");
    options.UseMySQL(connectionString, mySqlOptions => { });
});
```

I turned off firewall on my PC and I have added my IP on Azure, I use .NET 6.0, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0-rc.2 and EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.15

Comment: I'm actually working on a project on Azure with MySql too.
My connexion string is defined differently : Server=sqldb.mysql.database.azure.com;Uid=<adminuser>;Pwd=<password>;Database=<databasename>;

Comment: Your connection string znd ssms are both for ms sql server ad not for mysql. Did you mix up the names of your database product?

Comment: Another question. Which package do you use for mySQL ?
I'm using MySql.EntityFrameworkCode and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and UseMySQL options extension expects options => options.UseMySql(cnxString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cnxString))

Comment: I use pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql for mySQL

Comment: That's a SQL Server connection string. `1433` is the port used by SQL Server, not MySQL. SSMS can only connect to SQL Server, not MySQL. Which database are you actually using? You can't use providers and connection strings meant for one product to connect to a completely unrelated one

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to fix your connexion string and use the serverversion autodetect.
Try this

```
"con": "Server=amcia.database.windows.net;Uid=gryTerAdmin@amcia;Pwd=<password>;Database=amcia" 


builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    IConfiguration configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("con");
    options.UseMySQL(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
});
```